# Migration to Google Identity Services Library - App IDs/Client IDs cannot be found in GCP

Tags: google-signin

I received an email last night regarding migration to the new Google Identity Services library. I was expecting client IDs for my apps to be shown on the email, but instead it showed applications that I do not recognise and client IDs that I cannot find in Google Cloud.

Where could these have come from?

My account is a super administrator of Google Workspace, so perhaps this could have been for an old employee of my company?

I would like a way to find the apps.

I have tried searching credentials for all my existing applications, but these apps or client ids cannot be found.